# Wants to start Rspec in rails 3 how to start from basic to advance free

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tdd, rspec-rails

I wants to start TDD using Rspec so From where I should start

1) How to get Rspec integration in rails?
2) From where I can get documentation related help?
3) How I get basic guide to start and support to advance is available?
4) What gems combinations are best to use?
5) Need free resources not pricing related lectures

**Note:** Kindly don't provide Links which require login and pricing involved also don't need a heavy book :) I want to learn to the point things instead of reading a boring book.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to use rspec ? Or are you interested in the rspec-rails integration piece.

For the latter you can take a look at the [rspec-rails](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/frames) gem. Usually you'd update the `Gemfile` file in your rails project directory to include this gem for the dev and test environments. Then run

```
bundle update
```

That should install the gem. You then follow that up with this to create the spec folder et.all.

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

Now when you generate a model, it should create the stubs for the spec files as well.

I'm using the [Rspec book](http://rspec.info/) and [the pragprog rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) book. Still reading..

I see a [free tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org) that might work for you.

Comment: Brother, Frankly speaking just First link is help full for me :) Thanks for first link all other are asking for payment ;)

Comment: I found a zip of 3 screencasts on the last link.. Still to watch it. There's also a related question of 'tdd with rails' on this site that you can search for.. it has a link that test-drives a rails model from the ground up.